# Log4net detailed only for 1 particular user

Tags: asp.net, log4net

I'm using log4net to log errors/info for our website and it works great.

Is it possible to control the level of logging based on the user logged in/sessionid or something similar.  Ie. a user rings us with a problem and we turn on detailed logging just for them so we can troubleshoot but only slow down that user with detailed logging?

Obviously I could code explicitly but I was wondering if there is anything built into log4net?  Maybe by using the filters with global properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at Filters, maybe write your own. Or make your own log appender which does the filtering for you.

filter:

```
 <filter type="YourNameSpace.UserFilter">
     <user value="myusername"/>
 </filter>
```

and then implement the [SkeletonFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Filter.FilterSkeleton.html) class as YourNameSpace.UserFilter

If you use window authentication and impersonation you can also use the [log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter.html) which allows you to filter on properties in the message. The user can be found by the UserId property:

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
   <key value="UserID" />
   <stringToMatch value="MyUserName" />
</filter>
```